# Could not find valid value for id for event thankyou

Tags: civievent, paypal

after registering for an even using **PayPal - Website Payments Standard** (with the CiviCore processor) the transaction worked and email was fired but the user sees this instead of the thank you page.
this is the visible error:
`Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred. Could not find valid value for id`

using CiviCRM 5.41.2 on top of Wordpress 5.8.1
the line in question seems to be:

```
$is_monetary = CRM_Core_DAO::getFieldValue('CRM_Event_DAO_Event', $id, 'is_monetary');
```

$id is defined:

```
$id = CRM_Utils_Request::retrieve('id', 'Positive', $controller, TRUE);
```

stack:

```
Exception trace
#   Function    Location
0   CRM_Utils_Request::retrieve('id', 'Positive', Object(CRM_Event_Controller_Registration), true)  /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/StateMachine/Registration.php:27
1   CRM_Event_StateMachine_Registration->__construct(Object(CRM_Event_Controller_Registration), true)   /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Event/Controller/Registration.php:27
2   CRM_Event_Controller_Registration->__construct('Event Registrati…', true, 'null', null, 'false')    /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:308
3   CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem(Array) /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:69
4   CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke(Array) /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:36
5   CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke(Array)  /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php:1178
6   CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke() /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.basepage.php:354
7   CiviCRM_For_WordPress_Basepage->basepage_handler(Object(WP))    /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:303
8   WP_Hook->apply_filters(null, Array) /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:327
9   WP_Hook->do_action(Array)   /var/www/html/wp-includes/plugin.php:518
10  do_action_ref_array('wp', Array)    /var/www/html/wp-includes/class-wp.php:763
11  WP->main('')    /var/www/html/wp-includes/functions.php:1291
12  wp()    /var/www/html/wp-blog-header.php:16
13  require('/var/www/html/wp…')    /var/www/html/index.php:17
14  {main}   
Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
Could not find valid value for id

Return to home page.
```

logs: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/fVWgvKK4cc/

the link after registartion/paypal looks like https://example.org/civicrm/event/register?_qf_ThankYou_display=1&qfKey=CRMEventControllerRegistrationNUMBERSANDLETTERS_NUMBERS&PayerID=NUMBERSANDLETTERS

the **Test-drive** works as expected.
Example Link that works in test drive:
https://example.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Fregister&_qf_ThankYou_display=1&qfKey=CRMEventControllerRegistrationNUMBERSANDLETTERS_NUMBERS&PayerID=NUMBERSANDLETTERS
I'm not sure where to go from here.

More logs!!! "ID is:" after each conditional in retrieve -> CRM/Utils/Request.php
and more before the throw.

```
      error_log("_SESSION is: " . print_R($_SESSION, true));
      error_log("_GET is: " . print_R($_GET, true));
      error_log("_POST is: " . print_R($_POST, true));
      error_log("_REQUEST is: " . print_R($_REQUEST, true));
      error_log("_SERVER is: " . print_R($_SERVER, true));
      error_log("ID is: " . print_R($value, true));
```

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/sKd2Qkxknc/

Comment: you may need to add some info to your Q about your type of PayPal account and whether you are using core civi Payment Processor or eg Omnipay one. (not sure how PayPal gets set up so last point may be irrelevant)

Comment: Check if a redirect is happening in before loading the thank you page. This is often the cause of this error message - i.e. loss of session data.

Comment: Thank you @petednz-fuzion I updated the Q.

Comment: @ChristianWach what other values do you expect to see in the query string?

Comment: I don't think its missing a value in test drive it works but the link is different. I think it may be a route or WP vs CiviCRM thang.
Example Link that works in testdrive: 
https://example.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Fregister&_qf_ThankYou_display=1&qfKey=CRMEventControllerRegistrationNUMBERSANDLETTERS_NUMBERS&PayerID=NUMBERSANDLETTERS

Comment: @James The query string isn't the issue - the ID is stored in the session, which is cleared when CiviCRM loads the Thank You page. If there has been a redirect before loading the Thank You page, then the session will not have the ID. Try logging page loads in `wp-settings.php` and see if there's an unwanted one.

Comment: FWIW these redirects sometimes happen because `redirect_canonical()` traps what it thinks is an invalid URL and redirects to the "fixed" URL. The result is a loss of session data. Finding out if there's a redirect has to be the first step in debugging this.

Comment: @ChristianWach do you mean like this:

Request:

civicrm/event/register
Query String:
page_id=4&civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Fregister&reset=1&id=8

Matched Rewrite Rule:
^civicrm/([^?]*)?

Matched Rewrite Query:
page_id=4&civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Fregister

Comment: @James I'd log `$_REQUEST` in `wp-settings.php` (and pepper `redirect_canonical()` with logging code as well) to get a clear picture of what's occurring between submitting the payment and loading the Thank You page.

Comment: The "Matched Rewrite Query" is to be expected if you're using Clean URLs. That's not a redirect - just WordPress unpacking the URL.

Comment: @ChristianWach thanks for the continued support.
Looks like they match to me. (minus the uneeded '/') 
SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
/civicrm/event/register/?_qf_ThankYou_display=1&qfKey=CRMEventControllerRegistration4b72im9i3toggscock08gkc0oww48coc0cckw00cg4sk4w0gg0_8730&PayerID=RWUXETELQXTNN
redirect_url
http://127.0.0.1:8080/civicrm/event/register?_qf_ThankYou_display=1&qfKey=CRMEventControllerRegistration4b72im9i3toggscock08gkc0oww48coc0cckw00cg4sk4w0gg0_8730&PayerID=RWUXETELQXTNN

Comment: how does the ID get on the request?
(
    [_qf_ThankYou_display] => 1
    [qfKey] => CRMEventControllerRegistration4b72im9i3toggscock08gkc0oww48coc0cckw00cg4sk4w0gg0_2895
    [PayerID] => RWUXETELQXTNN
    [q] => civicrm/event/register
    [civiwp] => CiviCRM
    [noheader] => 1
)

Comment: "how does the ID get on the request?"

It's stored in the session.

I get the impression that you're focussing on the contents of one page load rather than tracking the sequence of page loads between the payment and Thank You page. I recommend focussing on that instead.

Comment: it has the id in the seesion before the redirect from 

/civicrm/event/register/?_qf_ThankYou_display....
to
/civicrm/event/register?_qf_ThankYou_display....
but not after.

Comment: (301 Moved Permanently)

Comment: how do I keep WP from redirecting? or civicrm from adding the extra / at the end before the query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out adding a '/' at the end of the Permalink Settings was made it work. I'm not sure how this ever worked.
From

```
/%category%/%post_id%/%postname%
```

To

```
/%category%/%post_id%/%postname%/
```

https://mysite.org/wp-admin/options-permalink.php